# No qualifying bean of type org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate with Spring Boot & Batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a strange problem. I made a Spring Batch application configurated and launched with Spring Boot. All my unit tests are passing.
But when I run program from command line :

`java -cp "./batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:." com.batch.BatchApplication`

I got a *No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]*.

If I run the same main class from Eclipse, all is working.

```
public class BatchApplication {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(BatchConfiguration.class, args)));
    }
}
```

Spring Boot "auto configuration" seems not working using command line.
Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `java -jar your-long-name.jar` (like in the docs and all the examples and guides). It uses a different main and makes the dependencies available at runtime.

Comment: No, if you see my classpath, I had "." to reference current directory for loading external resources. java -jar ... doesn't allow to extend classpath.

Comment: Yeah but your main class doesn't do anything smart either. If you need to add directories to the classpath look at one of the other main classes in Spring Boot (e.g. `PropertiesLauncher` http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features).

Comment: So, I can't use Spring Boot with standard (uber) java jar ? I need to use only Spring Boot jar format and Launcher system ? How can I externalize `application.properties` using `PropertiesLauncher` (command line arguments ?) ?

Comment: I don't understand those questions. Of course you can use an ueberjar (that's the whole point of the `*Launcher` main classes). Nothing changes with `application.properties` or command line arguments if you use `PropertiesLauncher`. Did you actually try it?

Comment: Actually I am creating uber jar using maven-assembly-plugin --> jar-with-dependencies not with spring-boot-maven-plugin (I am using maven 2...). So my main class is not a launcher but the main class above.

Comment: OK, then why not switch to using the Boot plugin? You can still use assembly if you really want, but you need to use the special main classes to get the jar to be executable.

Comment: I have try Boot plugin (with *ZIP* layout) with Maven 3. `java -Dloader.home=. -Dloader.path=. -jar batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` but it throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext`. If I do not override `loader.path`, I got a `FileNotFoundException` on my properties...

Comment: The loader classpath obviously has to include the ueberjar dependencies (in "classpath:/lib" if you used the Boot plugin).

Comment: `java -Dloader.home=. -Dloader.path=".,batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" -jar batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [batch-configuration.properties]` (file loaded using *@PropertySource*)

Comment: You didn't put the lib/ directory on the classpath yet, so I'm even surprised you got that far. Where is `batch-configuration.properties`?

Comment: I reference batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar that reference lib/ directory using default `PropertiesLaucher` paths (DEFAULT_PATHS). `batch-configuration.properties` is in same directory of *batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar* and *application.properties*. And is configurated like a classpath resource : `@PropertySource("batch-configuration.properties")`

Comment: I don't know why that doesn't work then. Can you put your `batch-configuration.properties` in `application.properties` to get it working?

Comment: I do not have only this file. I have log4j and other configurations files in this directory... And they are not loaded.

Comment: Then `application.properties` is not loaded either. Why don't you use `loader.path=.,lib`?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: I have try `loader.path=.,lib` but I always have the FileNotFoundException on my file. I am using Spring Boot v1.1.9.RELEASE.

Comment: Spring log `ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener: Application failed to start with classpath: ...` at startup and my custom "." directory seems not appears in the list

Comment: application.properties is loaded :
`2015-01-08 14:26:59,472 [main] DEBUG - Loaded config file 'file:./application.properties'`
seen here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files
I always try to search how to extend classpath for others resources

Comment: Yeah, but it's not loaded from the classpath is it? Your classpath is somehow missing the root of that jar. A simple test project to reproduce the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe you need to put the jar explicitly on the classpath before "."? (If you can avoid "." at all while we get stuff working that would be helpful. Why did you need it?)

Comment: I made a quick sample on github : https://github.com/Aure77/spring-boot-classpath-sample The "." seems to be the problem. I created a subfolder *ext* with properties. So `java -Dloader.path="ext,lib" -jar batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` works ! It's queer that "." is not working...

Comment: Thanks. Here's an issue to track it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2314

Comment: @DaveSyer I am using latest version of Spring Boot and ResourcePatternResolver can't load anything in the root of the jar when using 'classpath*:schemas/validator.json'. Also Liquibase can't find the scripts all in the root of the jar.